# CodeIgniter nested controllers?

Tags: codeigniter, nested, controllers

I'm new to CodeIgniter and I hope that my question will have a simple answer.

I have a website with a couple of menu items (menuA,menuB and menuC).
I have modeled it with one main controller, index(), menuA(), menuB() and menuC() in the controller. The called function sets a session value currentMenu and includes header, X, footer. Where X depends on the function called. The header then high lights the choosen menu.

Within menuC (Account settings in my webapp) I would like to have a different controller that controls subviews of AccountSettings/NotLoggedIn.

Logically I would like menuC() to include the header and the footer but then forward the call to a subcontroller that managed login or the sub pages.

Am I using the framwork wrong or is there a straight forward way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you should put some code here, because the answer may vary depending on your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it sounds like you're not understanding how to apply MVC to your structure. Picture it this way:

**Controllers** represent some facet of your application that users can interact with. For example, I could have an `items` controller that allows users to create, read, update, or delete `items`.  All the logic for interacting with `items` is handled by that controller (meaning it calls the `items` model and renders the necessary views).

In your case it sounds like you are building a `pages` controller that handles displaying the content for specific pages a user may call. So your controller could look something like this:

```
class Page extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        // Logic to render home page
    }

        public function about()
    {
        // Logic to render the about page
    }

    //  ... etc ...
```

**Views** can get a little tricky when you're dealing with complex sites that have overlap.  One of the most useful tricks I've discovered along the way is using a emplating library to reduce redundancy.  This is the one I use all the time: http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html . Using the template library you can easily define a layout that includes your header and footer and then just pass in a partial for the content you want to display.

When you want to deal with logic in something like a menu, all you need to do is pass in a variable with the page name and then do some basic PHP render the menu.

```
// Say we pass in a variable called $current to our view
// $current contains the name of the current page
// So say $current = 'About' for this example.


$sitemenu = array(
    array('/', 'Home'),
    array('/about', 'About'),
    array('/help', 'Page 2'),
    array('/contact', 'Page 3')
); ?>
<nav>
  <ul>
  <?php foreach( $sitemenu as $page) { ?>
     <?php if($current == $page[1]) { ?>
         <li class="current"><a href="<?php echo $page[0]; ?>"><?php echo $page[1]; ?></a></li>
     <?php } else { ?>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $page[0]; ?>"><?php echo $page[1]; ?></a></li>
     <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps!