# confused about codeigniter url route

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanna ask about CI System, what should I do, if i have 1 controller the URL is:

http://localhost/apanel
so that a controller **Apanel** I wanna make a 1 controller again and that effected in URL right ?

the new controller is **users** the url should be http://localhost/users
what should i do if I want make the URL like this http://localhost/apanel/users

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO :) If you want people to help you here, consider making it easier for them to understand your problem by providing more context, example *etc.* as described in their [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you can also make a subfolder called `apanel` in `controllers` that contains a php file like `Users.php` and it will be accessible via that url. If `apanel` is a type of CMS you are building e.g. backend system, then this method is what I personally use and recommend. Otherwise yes, you could use routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this, WORKS FOR ME:

```
$route['apanel/'] = "apanel/<method(default-- index)>";
$route['apanel/user'] = "apanel/<user-method>";
```

in your application>config>routes.php.

Hope this helps.
You can any type of routing here.

## for example:

```
$route['apanel'] = "apanel";
$route['apanel/create'] = "apanel/create";
$route['apanel/(:any)/user/(:any)'] = "apanel/user/$1/$2";
$route['apanel/(:any)/about/(:any)'] = "apanel/about/$1/$2";
```

Comment: this should be help me ill try this for now, i have a friend suggest, like this one

Comment: this absolutely working


`$route['apanel/user'] = "user";
$route['apanel/user/add'] = "user/add";
$route['apanel/user/delete/(:any)'] = "user/delet/$1";`

i was try it and work

Answer (score 1):

i think that should be so simple for you "Apanel" is a Controller and user is a function inside the Apanel Controller example :

```
class Apanel extends CI_Controller {
   public function index(){
     echo "you are at Apanel index function";
   }
   public function users(){
     echo "you are at users function";
   }
}
```

so URL

```
http://localhost/apanel
```

will give you output : (you are at Apanel index function) and

```
http://localhost/apanel/users
```

will give you output : (you are at users function)

Comment: yea i was know about the function and the controller in the case is, if i have a two controller, **Apanel** and i have a a controller **Users** how i can make the url link 

**localhost/controller1/controller2/function_controller_2**

Comment: you can create 2 controllers 1 : Apanel, 2nd : users then URLs will be like (http://localhost/apanel/ and http://localhost/users), but it sounds like you want nested controllers ? if yes then you have to move to HMVC code-igniter default is supported for MVC only there is HMVC version available for that as well.
see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683126/codeigniter-nested-controllers and this https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Answer (score 0):

It's actually simple . first go through some tutorial for CI.

In your case : http://localhost/apanel/users

Here apanel is your controller and users is the function under your apanel controller.

Reference  : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

inside of apanel controllerClass use put this code...

```
public function users(){
  require('Users.php');//calling Users Contrller class..
  $test = new Users();
  $test->methodYouWant();//call what method you wanto call..
}
```

Comment: can i call a model there ?, if i wanna add some data the method wil work ?